# How to find or add azure pipeline application published output folder for upload those files in to FTP

Tags: azure-devops

In the azure pipelines I'm trying to build a CI. I have added 'dotnet publish' in the agent job. But after publish, my application I have no idea where is those published files. There are no input field for enter output path.

I tried to use 'publishing artifacts' but it get wrong files

Here is my dotnet publish YAML

```
steps:
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'dotnet publish'
   inputs:
     command: publish
     workingDirectory: WebApplication1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find or add azure pipeline application published output folder for upload those files in to FTP

You can add the Arguments `--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` in the **Arguments** option to specify the output path:

[image]

Then it will zip as one zip file(a.zip) in the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` and you could use `publishing build artifacts` task to get it.

Hope this helps.